# S3 GetObject access for Facebook Messenger API

Tags: facebook, amazon-s3, facebook-messenger

I have a bucket of user images on Amazon S3 and I would like to allow access only to my Facebook Messenger bot. It seemed like the best way to do this was to create a bucket policy with a condition that only allows referrals from a Facebook url. But this doesn't work - the images fail to load in the bot.

Here is the bucket policy I created (trying both facebook.com and graph.facebook.com):

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Facebook referer policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from Facebook Messenger",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.facebook.com/*",
                        "https://www.graph.facebook.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I change the bucket policy back to public (as per below) then the images load fine so the problem must be an access one.

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone have any better solutions for how to do this?

Comment: I suspect you might be wrong on thinking that those requests "originated from" Messenger to begin with ... Facebook usually doesn't pass any such external image URLs on to end users directly - instead, their scraper requests the image, and stores copies on their own CDN to be delivered to users. There won't be any referrer ... what you want to look for, is the User-Agent of the Facebook scraper.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I thought this might be the case. Do you have any advice on how I might find out what the User-Agent of the Facebook scraper might be?

Comment: Type "facebook scraper user agent" into Google ...?

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to the comment above and the user agent documentation [from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler)

The working bucket policy is this:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": [
                        "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)",
                        "facebookexternalhit/1.1",
                        "Facebot"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```